# How to write a function that takes a user object, and returns the value of key?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently going through these exercises in JavaScript and came across the following question, but I'm not sure what exactly it's asking me or how to solve it? Should I be using if statements?

This is the question

> Write a function that takes a user object, and returns the value of
> key password. If there is no key of that name, it should return
> undefined.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> retrievePassword({name: 'Sam', password: 'hi!'})
> // returns "hi!"
> ```
>
> The platform passes in arguments automatically as follows:
>
> > Returns the password of a user Errors: `retrievePassword`'s output was
> > undefined, but it should be "chips!"
> >
> > Arguments:
> >
> > ```
> > { "name": "Sam", "password": "chips!" }
> >  Returns the password of a different user Errors: `retrievePassword`'s output was undefined, but it should be "fish!!!"
> > ```
> >
> > Arguments:
> >
> > ```
> > { "name": "Sam", "password": "fish!!!" }
> > ```

Comment: Post your implementation for help on what you did wrong

Answer (score 1):

Question states that `retrievePassword` takes Object as argument and returns the value of password (key) or else if password is not a key in given Object return `undefined`

Solution of the question is as follows:

```js
retrievePassword=(dict1)=>{
  return dict1.password
}
```

Working:

```js
retrievePassword({name: 'Sam', password: 'hi!'})
'hi!'

retrievePassword({name: 'Sam'})
undefined
```

Comment: The `|| undefined` portion is not needed. If `dict1.password` doesn't exist, `undefined` will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

From the requirement, I think you don't need to use `if` statement,  but return any value of `password`. If `password` is not defined, it will return `undefined` by default.

```js
const retrievePassword = (obj) => {
   return obj.password
}

console.log(retrievePassword({"name": "Sam", "password": "chips!" })) //chips!

console.log(retrievePassword({"name": "Sam", "password": "fish!!!" })) //fish!!!

console.log(retrievePassword({"name": "Sam" })) //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from you question i think that you have to write a function that gives back the password of the user object if that object contains the username's key, otherwise that function must return undefined.

If what i've just said is true then you need a function as follow:

```js
 let userObject = {
    "name" : "Michael",
    "password" : "myPassword"
  }
  let userObject2 = {
    "password" : "myPassword"
  }

  let retrievePassword = function(object){
    let password = object.password;
    let username = object.name;

    if(username){
      return password
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  }

  console.log(retrievePassword(userObject));
  console.log(retrievePassword(userObject2));
```

Comment: The `undefined` test portion is not needed. If `password` doesn't exist, `undefined` will be returned.